# Changing views on button click?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments

- I want to switch between listview and grid view on button click.
- The data is fetched via network using volley.

I've found 3 ways of doing so and all of them are working
 - Creating 2 fragments and changing them
 - Using view switcher
 - Changing the visibility of the view on button click

I want to know which one of the above should be used, given that the user will frequently switch between them.

Comment: creating 2 fragments will be the more cleaner way to code as compared to other two

Comment: what about performance...won't attaching fragment then calling adapter will consume more time comparing to the 3rd way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice using a `RecyclerView` instead of the old `ListView`. With the `RecyclerView` you could set a different layout manager.

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

For a normal list, and

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this));
```

For a grid representation of the data.

You can find more information here: [Create lists and cards](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).